# FOSUserBundle, How include own stylesheet files?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I want change default style for login form in FOSUserBundle. In my bundle, in views/layout.html.twig I write this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link href="{{ asset('/bundles/user/css/demo.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
{% block body %}
{{ block('fos_user_content') }}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Then in terminal I put this:

```
app/console assets:install web --symlink
```

After that I get web/bundles/user/css/demo.css

But after cleaning cache FireBug don't show any included css files...why ?

Comment: the stylesheet does not show up in the source code or it does not get loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just override the **FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig** via bundle inheritance by creating your template at:

```
app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/layout.html.twig
```

this template has to contain the block **fos_user_content**.

The original base template for FOSUserBundle can be found [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/layout.html.twig).

Further reading in the cookbook article [Overriding Bundle Templates](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#overriding-bundle-templates).

Comment: Thank you. You are my personal Symfony teacher :). You help me again.

Comment: hehe glad i could help again :D happy coding!